# Concatenation of php class static variables

Tags: php, class, static, variables

My first class:

```
<?php
  require_once( 'error/DisconnectedHandler.php' );
  require_once( 'error/NoSuchRequestHandler.php' );

  class NetworkManager {

  public static final $RESPONSE_JUMP = 1000;
  ....
```

My second class:

```
<?php
    require_once( '../NetworkManager.php' );

    class DisconnectedHandler implements Handler{
        public static $TYPE          = 2000;
        public static $RESPONSE_TYPE = self::$TYPE + NetworkManager::$RESPONSE_JUMP;
        public static $VER           = 0;
```

I get an error in this line:

```
public static $RESPONSE_TYPE = self::$TYPE + NetworkManager::$RESPONSE_JUMP;
```

Eclipse IDE paint `$TYPE` in red and says:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- syntax error, unexpected '$TYPE', expecting 
 'identifier'
- syntax error, unexpected '$TYPE', expecting 
 'identifier'
```

What is the correct syntax for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Static variable declarations (as well as class constants) must be literally defined and cannot contain expression as they are evaluated prior to runtime.

You have to initialize your `DisconnectedHandler::$RESPONE_TYPE` in a constructor or more likely in a static initializer method.